# How can I match the colors between the subset and the original image?

Tags: erdas-imagine, subset

I have test subset using an AOI, and I have unchecked the "Ignore zeros in stats." option in the subset dialogue box. The difference in colors may have been cause by the histogram re-distribution as a consequence of having the minimum and maximum DN value changed in the subset image from the original image. Is there a method I can preserve the original colors ?[image]

Comment: I'm not too familiar with Erdas-Imagine but if it's anything like QGIS, you can set the minimum and maximum pixel values manually for the histogram stretch. Setting them to match the minimum and maximum values of the original image would preserve the colours.